# Why should the spatial derivative order of the ODE *not* exceed two?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, finite-element-method

Following this [`question`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91142/1089) I came across this strange behaviour.

Let me define a 1 D interval implicitely

```
a = 1; b = 2;
Ω = ImplicitRegion[a <= r <= b, {r}]
```

and let me try to solve PDEs on this interval.

This works as expected (second order ODE)

```
w1 = NDSolveValue[{w''[r] == 1/2,
   DirichletCondition[w[r] == 0, r == a], 
   DirichletCondition[w[r] == 0, r == b]}, w, {r, a, b}]

Plot[w1[x], x ∈ Ω]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and so does this

```
w2 = NDSolveValue[{w''[r] == 1/2,
   DirichletCondition[w[r] == 0, r == a], 
   DirichletCondition[w[r] == 0, r == b]}, w, r ∈ Ω]
```

This works again as expected (this time 4th order ODE)

```
w1 = NDSolveValue[{w''''[r] == 1/2,
   DirichletCondition[w[r] == 0, r == a], 
   DirichletCondition[w'[r] == 0, r == a], 
   DirichletCondition[w[r] == 0, r == b], 
   DirichletCondition[w'[r] == 0, r == b]}, w, {r, a, b}]


Plot[w1[x], x ∈ Ω]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Question

> But why does this fail?

```
w2 = NDSolveValue[{w''''[r] == 1/2,
   DirichletCondition[w[r] == 0, r == a], 
   DirichletCondition[w'[r] == 0, r == a], 
   DirichletCondition[w[r] == 0, r == b], 
   DirichletCondition[w'[r] == 0, r == b]}, w, r ∈ Ω]
```

with the error message  `The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two. >>`

The only difference being using `r ∈ Ω` as a domain instead of `{r,a,b}`.

Comment: I think it may be a limitation of the FEM code.

Comment: @MichaelE2 But why does it switch to the FEM code if the default code works?

Comment: I was just about to add: Because in the non-working code, you use regions. -- That is to say, the use of regions causes `NDSolve` to go to FEM, without looking at whether the region is amenable to other methods.

Comment: @MichaelE2 it is a pity though is it not?

Comment: If region == trivial use simple code ? :-)

Comment: It seems unnecessary, yes.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The question that this question sprouted from (my question) suggests that the utility of mma be displayed by the use of FEM EVEN if it is a rather trivial problem that needs no complicating through the use of `Regions`. I understand your point though.

Comment: It's probably irrelevant, but conceptually spatial regions have no innate direction but time does.  That fact that `Ω` could be viewed as having a direction and therefore integrated over as if it were time is a coincidence of it being 1D and the necessity of describing it in terms of a coordinate system.  Still, you'd think it could say "FEM failed; integrating as an ODE with temporal variable `r`."

Comment: It's also annoying that explicitly setting the `Method` to something other than `"FiniteElement"` makes no difference. You do not even get a warning that it is being ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right now (V11.3) `NDSolve` uses FEM for elliptic PDEs and that code does up to 2nd order spatial derivatives. The fact that this PDE can be viewed as a time dependent ODE is a coincidence in 1D as pointed out by @MichaelE2 and time dependent ODE are specified via explicit bounds. Another, harder, issue is that it is not trivial to write a general test to see if an `ImplicitRegion` is "Simple". Also, this test needs time to execute. This needs to be run for every `ImplicitRegion`also `ParametricRegions` basically everything that is `RegionQ` and the number of cases where it could help is, I feel, very limited compared to the time it is going to take. Having to specify explicit boundaries is not that bad I think. What possibly could work is to add an indication to the message that this could be solved as a transient ODE or have an example in the `>>` link. I'll make that a suggestion.

*Update:*

You can find the message documentation for this now in the help system by directing it to *FEMDocumentation/ref/message/InitializePDECoefficients/femcmsd*