# Solving a 4th order PDE (Plate bending)

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following PDE but I'm getting this error. The PDE represents the bending of a thin plate.

```
 NDSolve[{
     D[w[x, y], {x, 4}] + D[w[x, y], {y, 4}] + D[w[x, y], x, y, x,y] == 10,
     w[0, y] == 0,
     w[x, 0] == 0,
     w[5, y] == 0, 
     w[x, 3] == 0,
     D[w[0, y], {y, 2}] == 0,
     D[w[5, y], {y, 2}] == 0,
     D[w[x, 0], {x, 2}] == 0, 
     D[w[x, 3], {x, 2}] == 0},
     w, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

The error is:

> NDSolve::femcmsd: The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two. >>

Comment: See this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91150/why-should-the-spatial-derivative-order-of-the-ode-not-exceed-two