# Circular plane stress

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I would like to calculate the displacement function of a circular plane with a circular hole in the center, along which it is interlocked.

I thought about solving with the following code:

```
domain = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 4^2 && x^2 + y^2 >= 2^2, {x, y}];
pde = D[w[x, y], {x, 4}] + 2 D[w[x, y], {x, 2}, {y, 2}] + D[w[x, y], {y, 4}] == 1;
bcs1 = DirichletCondition[w[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 == 2^2];
bcs2 = DirichletCondition[D[w[x, y], {x, 2}] == 0, x^2 + y^2 == 2^2];
bcs3 = DirichletCondition[D[w[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0, x^2 + y^2 == 2^2];
NDSolveValue[{pde, bcs1, bcs2, bcs3}, w[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] domain]
```

but unfortunately I get the following error:

> NDSolveValue::femcmsd: The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two.

Can you correct me, please? Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that Mathematica does not currently support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's partially explained in the [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91269/53855). Since you use regions, Mathematica has to go for FEM solver. Unfortunately, its FEM solver doesn't support derivatives greater than 2 (that's what the error message is about).