# NDSolve uses different difference order for different spatial derivative when solving PDE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, implementation-details

I found something [this tutorial for method of line](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) doesn't tell us.

Consider the following toy example:

```
eqn = With[{u = u[x, t]}, 
   D[u, t] == D[u, x] + D[u, {x, 2}] + D[u, {x, 3}] - D[u, {x, 4}]];

ic = u[x, 0] == 0;
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0, D[u[x, t], x] == 0 /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> 1}}};
  
NDSolve[{eqn, ic, bc},
 u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}]
```

Guess what difference order is chosen when those spatial derivatives (in this case $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}$, $\frac{\partial ^3u}{\partial x^3}$, $\frac{\partial ^4u}{\partial x^4}$) are discretized?

"What a needless question! The order is `4`, as we set with `"DifferenceOrder" -> 4`! " About an hour ago, I thought so, too. But it's not true. Let's check the difference formula generated by `NDSolve`:

```
state = First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eqn, ic, bc},
    u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}];
funcexpr = state["NumericalFunction"]["FunctionExpression"]
```

> Introduction for `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations `` can be found in
> [`tutorial/NDSolveStateData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) and [`tutorial/NDSolveDAE`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html).

[image]

Then check the `"DifferenceOrder"` of these `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivativeFunction ``:

```
Head[#]@"DifferenceOrder" & /@ funcexpr[[2, 1]]
(* {{7}, {6}, {5}, {4}} *)
```

The order is not `4`! Similarly, we can verify that it's the same case for PDE system:

```
eqn = 
  With[{u = u[x, t], v = v[x, t]}, 
       {D[u, t] == D[u, x] + D[u, {x, 2}] + D[u, {x, 3}] - D[u, {x, 4}], 
        D[v, t] == D[v, x] + D[v, {x, 2}]}];
ic = {u[x, 0] == 0, v[x, 0] == 0};
bc = {{u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0, 
       D[u[x, t], x] == 0 /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> 1}}}, 
      {v[0, t] == 0, v[1, t] == 0}};

state = 
  First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eqn, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}];
funcexpr = state["NumericalFunction"]["FunctionExpression"]

Head[#]@"DifferenceOrder" & /@ funcexpr[[2, 1]]
(* {{7}, {7}, {6}, {6}, {5}, {4}} *)
```

So, **for a PDE or PDE system whose maximum spatial differential order is `omax`, when `"DifferenceOrder" -> n` is set for `"TensorProductGrid"`, the actual difference order for `m`-order spatial derivative is `omax + n - m`**.

In certain cases, this design seems to cause trouble, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128725/1871)'s an example.

To make this post a question, I'd like to ask:

1. Why `NDSolve` chooses this design?
2. If the 1st question is too hard, is there a easy way (e.g. a hidden option) to make `NDSolve` use the same difference order for every spatial derivative?

Answer (score 19):

> **Note:** `fix` is broken since *v11.3*, [a new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/202668/1871) has
>   been started aiming at upgrade it.

Here's my approach for fixing the difference order. The key idea is modifying the `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivativeFunction `` inside `` NDSolve`StateData `` directly:

```
Clear[tosameorder, fix]
tosameorder[state_NDSolve`StateData, order_] := 
 state /. a_NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivativeFunction :> 
   RuleCondition@NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[a@"DerivativeOrder", a@"Coordinates", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> order, PeriodicInterpolation -> a@"PeriodicInterpolation"]

fix[endtime_, order_] := 
 Function[{ndsolve}, 
  Module[{state = First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations @@ Unevaluated@ndsolve], newstate}, 
    newstate = tosameorder[state, order]; NDSolve`Iterate[newstate, endtime]; 
   Unevaluated[ndsolve][[2]] /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions@newstate], HoldAll]
```

Example:

```
bound = 0.25510204081632654;
upper = 99/100; lower = 1 - upper;
range = {L, R} = {-Pi/2, Pi/2};
endtime = 100;
xdifforder = 4;
eqn = With[{h = h[t, θ], ϵ = 5/10}, 
   0 == -D[h, t] + D[h^3 (1 - h)^3 ϵ D[h, θ], θ]];
ic = h[0, θ] == 
   Simplify`PWToUnitStep@Piecewise[{{upper, -bound < θ < bound}}, lower];
bc = {h[t, L] == lower, h[t, R] == lower};

mol[n_Integer, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

With[{nd := 
   NDSolveValue[{eqn, ic, bc}, h, {t, 0, endtime}, {θ, L, R}, 
    Method -> mol[200, xdifforder], MaxSteps -> Infinity]}, 
 With[{sol = nd, sold = fix[endtime, xdifforder]@nd}, 
  Animate[Plot[{sol[t, th], sold[t, th]}, {th, L, R}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"Before fix", "After fix"}], {t, 0, endtime}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: two questions to consult: 1. is there a way to check that with your `fix` function, `NDSolve` indeed uses the same difference order for all the spatial derivatives? 2. Whether or not the `fix` function can be applied when solving 2 coupled equations with `NDSolveValue`? Btw, I found when solve 2 eqns with different highest spatial-derivative orders, your conclusion in OP would be modified as *For a system of PDEs whose maximum spatial differential order is **omax=max{eqn_1, eqn_2, ... eqn_i} ...***

Comment: @Nobody 0. Do notice `fix` has been broken since _v11.3_. 1. Well, I think it's clear if one understands the source code of `fix`. Anyway, if you want to check, just add a `Sow` to my `fix` and use `Reap` to extract the modified `NDSolve\`StateData[……]` and do what I've done in the question. 2. Yes, it works for PDE system. 3. Thx for pointing out. The statement in the question is revised.

Comment: @zxczd, thanks, I am still a big fan of v.9, based on my personal experience it is often better than v11.3 at least in the aspect of numerical analysis :)

Comment: @zxczd, for the highest derivatives does `NDSovle` always use implicit representation of finite difference? If not, how could we know the scheme?

Comment: @jsxs What do you mean by "implicit representation of finite difference"?

Comment: @xzczd sorry I should state it more clear. I meant implicit scheme in space derivative, that is, representing the derivative using some unknown data in the next time step... opposite to the explicit scheme. I'd like to discuss this point since I think this may be associated with your question: "why NDSolve chooses this design?"

Comment: @jsxs If you mean implicit difference scheme, then I'm afraid you've misunderstood `MethodOfLines`. `NDSolve` is not using finite difference method in $t$ direction, it uses an ODE or DAE solver. Please read the **Introduction** section of the tutorial [The Numerical Method of Lines](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) carefully.

Comment: @xzczd thank you, so all the spatial derivations use explicit schemes on the current time step in MethodOfLines.

Comment: @jsxs Once again, it's not "explicit/implicit scheme", because data forward/backward in time is not used at all. To understand how the ODE/DAE solver works, consider reading https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871

Answer (score 14):

Complete control over the spatial decomposition of the PDE given in the answer by [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd) can be achieved by decomposing the PDE into a large set of ODEs, as described in the Introduction to the [Numerical Method of Lines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html), provided in the Mathematica documentation.  The following straightforward approach uses a uniform grid and second-order differencing.

```
Clear[u];
n = 200; d = (R - L)/n;
vars = Table[u[i, t], {i, 2, n}]; u[1, t] = lower; u[n + 1, t] = lower; 
eq = Table[dup = (u[i + 1, t] - u[i, t])/d; dum = (u[i, t] - u[i - 1, t])/d; 
    up = (u[i + 1, t] + u[i, t])/2; um = (u[i, t] + u[i - 1, t])/2;
    D[u[i, t], t] == (up^3 (1 - up)^3 dup - um^3 (1 - um)^3 dum) ϵ/d, {i, 2, n}];
init = Table[u[i, 0] == Piecewise[{{upper, -bound < L + (i - 1) d < bound}}, lower], 
    {i, 2, n}];
s = NDSolveValue[{eq, init}, vars, {t, 0, endtime}];
ListLinePlot[Evaluate@Table[Join[{lower}, 
    Table[s[[i - 1]] /. t -> tt, {i, 2, n}], {lower}], 
    {tt, 0, endtime, endtime/10}], DataRange -> range, PlotRange -> 1]
```

[image]

A test of the accuracy of this result can be obtained by noting that the integral of `D[h, t]` (using the nomenclature in the answer by xzczd) over `range` is given by

```
h^3 (1 - h)^3 ϵ D[h, θ]
```

evaluated at `R` minus the same quantity evaluated at `L`.  Moreover, numerical evaluation of this quantity at the two endpoints shows that it is very small.  In other words, the integral of `h` over `range` should be essentially constant in time.  The solution obtained here indeed is constant when integrated over `range`, as can be shown by evaluating

```
Table[Total@N@Table[s[[i - 1]] /. t -> tt, {i, 2, n}] d, {tt, 0, endtime, endtime/20}]
(* {0.539254, 0.539254, ..., 0.539254, 0.539254} *)
```

Consider, now, the "before fix" and "after fix" solutions obtained by xzczd and plotted here for `t == endtime`.

[image]

The "after fix" solution is similar but not identical to the solution `t == endtime` curve shown in the first plot of this answer.  Moreover, the conserved quantity just described also varies in time.

```
ListPlot[Table[Quiet@NIntegrate[sold[t, th], {th, L, R}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}], 
    {t, 0, endtime, endtime/20}], DataRange -> {0, endtime}]
```

[image]

All this is not to suggest that xzczd's elegant answer (+1) is incorrect.  In fact, merely increasing the number of grid points to `5000` reduces temporal variation of the conserved quantity in the "after fix" solution to within 0.5%,

[image]

and yields for `t == endtime`,

[image]

and the "after fix" curve is identical to the eye to the `t == endtime` curve in the first plot of this answer.  Note that increasing the number of grid points does nothing to improve the accuracy of the "before fix" solution.

Comment: Interesting! You may also give an answer to [that question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128447/1871), I think your difference scheme is exactly what [ojlm](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/37792/ojlm) needs.

Comment: @xzczd  As I look more at the ojlm's approach, I see that he analytically differentiates the right side of the PDE and then replaces the first and second spatial derivatives by their finite differences.  My approach is to form the second-order finite difference without first analytically expanding the derivative, which I believe to be more accurate.  I shall look in greater detail at this distinction tomorrow morning.

Comment: @xzczd  You ask interesting questions, and I have learned quite a bit from this one and others of yours that I have examined this past week.  Thanks also for the bounty.

Comment: [教学相长](http://eng.ichacha.net/%E6%95%99%E5%AD%A6%E7%9B%B8%E9%95%BF.html) :D