# Fixing the difference order for space derivatives in a PDE when using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to implement the fix to make the difference order uniform for all space derivatives in a PDE, as described in this post: [NDSolve uses different difference order for different spatial derivative when solving PDE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129183/ndsolve-uses-different-difference-order-for-different-spatial-derivative-when-so/129193#129193)

It does not work, and I am out of my wits as to why. (Actually, it is the system of 2 coupled PDEs that I am solving.) After the system is set up I included the standard call to `NDSolve` to show that the problem was set up correctly, and then in the end there is a minimal implementation of the fix. As I wrote it, it does not work, although the the output indicates that time stepping was performed. Can anyone please help?

```
Clear[tosameorder, fix]
tosameorder[state_NDSolve`StateData, order_] := 
state /. a_NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivativeFunction :> 
NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[a@"DerivativeOrder", 
a@"Coordinates", "DifferenceOrder" -> order, 
PeriodicInterpolation -> a@"PeriodicInterpolation"]

fix[endtime_, order_] := 
Function[{ndsolve}, 
Module[{state = 
First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations @@ Unevaluated@ndsolve], 
newstate}, newstate = tosameorder[state, order]; 
NDSolve`Iterate[newstate, endtime];
Unevaluated[ndsolve][[2]] /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions@newstate], 
HoldAll]

RHSCeq = D[H[t, x], x] D[Subscript[C, Bb][t, x], x, x]; 
RHSHeq = Subscript[C, Bb][t, x] D[H[t, x], x, x]; 
Nkmax = 6.482250811894023; 
Nλmax = 2 Pi/Nkmax;

domainlength = 20 Nλmax; center1 = domainlength/8; w1 = 0.05; 
IniShapeH = 1 - 0.02 Exp[-(x - center1)^2/w1^2];
IniShapeC = 1/2;

Δt = 0.1

solution = 
NDSolve[{D[Subscript[C, Bb][t, x], t] == RHSCeq, 
D[H[t, x], t] == RHSHeq, 
Subscript[C, Bb][t, 0] == Subscript[C, Bb][t, domainlength], 
H[t, 0] == H[t, domainlength], Subscript[C, Bb][0, x] == IniShapeC,
H[0, x] == IniShapeH, 
WhenEvent[Mod[t, Δt] == 0, Print[t]]}, {Subscript[C, 
Bb], H}, {x, 0, domainlength}, {t, 0, 1}, 
AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision/2, 
PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision/2, InterpolationOrder -> All, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
  "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, MinPoints -> 1000, MaxPoints -> 1000, 
  AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision/2, 
  PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision/2}, 
Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", 
  "Coefficients" -> "ImplicitRungeKuttaRadauIIACoefficients", 
  "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}]

Plot[{IniShapeH, First[H[1, x] /. solution]}, {x, 0, domainlength}, 
PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.0055], Black}, {Thickness[0.0055], Blue}}]

Plot[{IniShapeC, First[Subscript[C, Bb][1, x] /. solution]}, {x, 0, 
domainlength}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.0055], Black}, {Thickness[0.0055], Blue}}]

endtime = 1; nspacepoints = 1000; xdifforder = 4; 

mol[n_Integer, o_] := {"MethodOfLines", 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
"MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

nd := NDSolveValue[{D[Subscript[C, Bb][t, x], t] == RHSCeq, 
D[H[t, x], t] == RHSHeq, 
Subscript[C, Bb][t, 0] == Subscript[C, Bb][t, domainlength], 
H[t, 0] == H[t, domainlength], Subscript[C, Bb][0, x] == IniShapeC,
H[0, x] == IniShapeH, 
WhenEvent[Mod[t, Δt] == 0, Print[t]]}, {Subscript[C, 
Bb], H}, {x, 0, domainlength}, {t, 0, endtime}, 
Method -> mol[nspacepoints, xdifforder]]

sold = fix[endtime, xdifforder]@nd
```

Comment: @xzczd Thank you! But how to extract solution from sold ? Plot[{IniShapeH, First[H[x, 0.1] /. sold]}, {x, 0, domainlength}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.0055], Black}, {Thickness[0.0055], Blue}}] results in error ..

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a matter of evaluation order. Notice that in my answer, I've defined `nd` with a `With[{nd:= ……}, ……]` structure. Why? Because the last "step" inside `fix` is

```
Unevaluated[ndsolve][[2]] /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions@newstate
```

The `Unevaluated[ndsolve][[2]]` part is for extracting the dependent variable from `ndsolve`, which requires the dependent variables to **explictly** exist. If you simply define `nd:=……` without `With`, `nd` will still be `nd` inside `Unevaluated`. In other words, what happened here can be reproduced with the following example:

```
lst := {a, b}
Unevaluated[lst][[2]]
```

> Part::partd

In this example, though the `OwnValues` of `lst` is `{a, b}`, when it's not evaluated, it's no more than a `Symbol` in `Part`'s eyes, so the code doesn't work as expected.

Then why it'll work if I define `nd` with a `With`? Because the… Er… scoping mechanism of `With` is quite similar to rule substitution. When e.g.

```
With[{lst := {a, b}}, Unevaluated[lst][[2]]]
```

is executed, `lst` in `Unevaluated[lst][[2]]` is simply replaced by `{a, b}`.

So, to fix your code, we just need to replace `nd` with the code inside `nd` e.g.  modify the last line to:

```
sold = Unevaluated@fix[endtime, xdifforder][nd] /. OwnValues@nd
```

Comment: Thank you ! But how to extract the solution from sold ? Plot[{IniShapeH, First[H[0.1,x] /. sold]}, {x, 0, domainlength}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.0055], Black}, {Thickness[0.0055], Blue}}] results in error ..

Comment: Notice `sold` is already a `List` of `InterpolatingFunction` so `sold[[1]]` is the solution for `Subscript[C, 
Bb]` and `sold[[2]]` is the solution for `H`.